# Unable to access RTC(Rational Team Concert) from RESTdebugger, embarcadero

Tags: c++, delphi

Unable to authenticate to RTC , tool complains saying “authfailed”, although credentials are correct.
However,the same request is working fine with the “REST client” from  Mozilla add-ons.see the snapshot of the request below
[image]

Below is the Response body for the above request

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
        dojo.addOnLoad( function() {
            net.jazz.ajax.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench("com.ibm.team.rtc.web.rationalTeamConcertWeb");
        });
    /* ]]> */
    </script>
```

Below is the Rest debugger from embarcadero

[image]

The body of the REST debugger looks like below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
  Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
  (c) Copyright IBM Corporation 2005, 2015. All Rights Reserved.

  Note to U.S. Government Users Restricted Rights:
  Use, duplication or disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule
  Contract with IBM Corp.
-->

<html >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">
<title></title>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/ccm/web/_style/?include=B~&etag=FtegUJp7asn_en_US&_proxyURL=%2Fccm&ss=MlBwU">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/ccm/web/net.jazz.ajax/jazz.ico">

<style type="text/css">
#net-jazz-ajax-NoScriptMessage {
    width: 100%;
    color: #D0D0D0;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1%;
    z-index: 999;
}
</style>

</head>

<body class="claro">
    <noscript><div id="net-jazz-ajax-NoScriptMessage">Javascript is either disabled or not available in your Browser</div></noscript>
    <div id="net-jazz-ajax-InitialLoadMessage">Loading...</div>
    <div id="net-jazz-ajax-WorkbenchRoot"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        djConfig = {
            isDebug: false,
            layout: "",
            usePlainJson: true,
            baseUrl: "/ccm/web/dojo/",
            locale: "en-us",
            localizationComplete: true
        };
        /*null*/
        net = {jazz: {ajax: {}}};
        net.jazz.ajax._contextRoot = "/ccm";
        net.jazz.ajax._appPath = "/ccm/auth/authfailed";
        net.jazz.ajax._webuiPrefix = "/web/";
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ccm/web/_js/?include=B~&etag=FtegUJp7asn_en_US&_proxyURL=%2Fccm&ss=MlBwU&locale=en-us"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
require("dojo/main").getObject('jazz.core.loader', true)._serverStartup="MlBwU";
require("dojo/main").getObject('jazz.core.loader',true)._loaded=["B"];
</script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
        dojo.addOnLoad( function() {
            net.jazz.ajax.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench("net.jazz.web.app.authfailed");
        });
    /* ]]> */
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Delphi version is 10.2

Comment: Please indicate how you're calling it from the Mozilla add-on. I would not expect authentication to be performed via entries in the body

Comment: updated the description

Comment: The response says 1986 bytes of data returned. What is in the Body? What version of Delphi is the REST Debugger from?

Comment: I mean for REST Debugger. The picture just shows the Headers

Comment: Updates the description with the content of the body